# How to proof the Interior and clousure of subset of R^3

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I have this problem where I have to find the closure and the interior of the following set 
$$ A=\{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \} $$

The graph of this is a circle in the space, which is laying on the plane XY, so to find the biggest open set contained in A, the interior, I propose it to be the ball $B_1(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $ but If I take it to be radius one, I won't be able to cover the boundary of A and so to be fully contained in such ball the radious should be something like $1+\epsilon$ or maybe $1+ \frac{1}{n}$. On the other hand, to establish the closure means finding a closed set, the smallest such that is fully contained in A which is the same ball as before $B_1(0)$ but closed $\overline{B_1(0)}$.

The questions here are:

1. Is it right to think that $int(A)=B_{1+\epsilon}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ 
   and $\overline{A}=\overline{B_{1}(0)} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ ?
2. If so, how can I prove this?

I'm still trying to get used to working with topologies on metric spaces, and even though I think is much more visual than the abstract one, having to find closures and interiors of this kind of subsets aren't easy for me. Do you have any book you would recommend which focuses only on metric spaces topology?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Balls in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are three-dimensional. You cannot have one that lies completely inside a plane.

Comment: $A = f^{-1}[ [0,1] ]$ where $f(\vec{x}) = x^2 + y^2$

Comment: The interior of $A$ is not the ball in $mathbb{R}^2$. The last coordinate, $z$, is free in $A$ so you should think of A as a full cylinder.

Comment: The interior of $A$  is $B_1(0).$ The points of the boundary of $A$ are not members of the interior.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. I changed the exponent 3 to 2. It seems to have been a typo.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet.  I've got your point since the plot of such equation is a cylinder I can't cover it with any circle (ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$) . But  I don't see clearly which is the interior of A, you said $B_1(0)$ but meaning a ball in space or in the plane? . If it is in space sure I can cover the cylinder with a sphere but isn't it  a much more bigger open set?  Does it matter?

Comment: @DominiqueMATTEI OH you're totally right!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So because $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ is a cylinder I cannot cover it with circles even if I stack them somehow (kind of)?

Comment: A solid cylinder does have an interior: the open cyclinder, $x^2 + y^2 < 1$.

Comment: Oh! Sounds completely right, but how can I prove such claim?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Meaning taking a point in $int(A)=\{ \vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2 < 1\}$ how can I find a open set which has the point. Could it be the open sphere of radious 1?

Comment: I have undone my previous edit back to your original post.

Comment: The continuity of the $x^2 + y^2$ function also implies $\{ \vec x \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$ is open.  From there, all that would be left to prove is that points with $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ are *not* in the interior.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see clearly how  the continuity of $x^2+y^2$ implies the set is open (1) on the other hand, to prove $x^2+y^2=1$ are not in the interior, suppose there are in the interior, how can I take a point is such set? and prove somehow a contradiction (2). Thanks for your time, really!

Answer (score 1):

As the comments above noted, $A$ is closed is $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the usual Euclidean topology on it.

To see why this is true, note that $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ (where $\mathbb{R}$ also has the standard Euclidean topology) defined by $f(x, y, z) = f(\vec{x}) = x^2 + y^2$ is a continuous map. Then observe that $A = f^{-1}\left[[0, 1]\right]$ and certainly $[0, 1]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. By continuity of $f$ we then have $A$ to be closed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ because the preimage of a closed set is closed for any continuous function. Finally since $A$ is closed we can conclude that $\overline{A} = A$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did't think that way.

Comment: I mean $f(\vec{x})$ is clearly continuous in  $\mathbb{R}^3$ but does it imply to be continuous in the topological sense?  Or do I have to prove it, which using the closed sets, comes back to prove that A is closed.

Comment: @LilianHernández That's a good question. The key realization to make is that $\mathbb{R}^3$ (as people usually refer to it, and how I referred to it in my answer above) is a topological space. Explicitly when I say *'$\mathbb{R}^3$ with the usual Euclidean topology"* I mean the topological space $(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathcal{T})$ where the topology $\mathcal{T}$ is the topology given by the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{B_{(\mathbb{R}^3, d)}(\vec{x}, r) \ | \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 \text{ and } r > 0 \}$ where $d(\vec{a}, \vec{b}) = \sqrt{(a_1 - b_1)^2 + (a_2 -b_2)^2 + (a_3 - b_3)^2}$.

Comment: In words $\mathcal{B}$ is the set of all open balls coming from $(\mathbb{R}^3, d)$ viewed as a metric space. Note that we call this metric $d$ the "Euclidean metric" and the topology $\mathcal{T}$ given by the basis $\mathcal{B}$ the "Euclidean topology" on $\mathbb{R}^3$. I apologize if I confused you in this discussion, (if you are confused then just let me know and I can explain further) but the point I'm trying to make is that the moral of this story is that we can't have continuity of maps between mathematical structures without imposing some sort of topology on them.

Comment: Most authors don't mention this explicitly, for example when one studies metric spaces some authors/lecturers can introduce the concepts of open/closed subsets of metric spaces and continuous maps between metric spaces without directly referencing topology, but when you start learning general topology (often called point-set topology) you see that actually you've been working with a topology on your metric spaces all along because any metric on a metric space (a set with a metric) induces a topology from the basis of open balls generated by the metric.

Comment: So to say that something is continuous in one sense and not a topological sense is not entirely correct, because whenever one discusses continuity of maps between mathematical structures (e.g sets, groups, fields , vector spaces, topological manifolds etc.) there is always some underlying topology that is lurking somewhere in the background. You could always verify directly that continuity in one sense implies continuity in the topological sense, but to do so is beside the point I believe.

Comment: I appreciate the time spent, thank you!. And I see,  continuity in one sense, saying analytic, implies or has somehow topology behind. But can I prove that A is closed without having to work with continuity ?

Comment: And yep, I know what you meant,  The topology induced by the basis is the one in which all the open sets are seen as union of balls, therefore for example that the interior of the cylinder is the open cylinder $x^2+y^2<1$ is visually trivial but to prove such claim I have to show somehow in the classical sense there exists a open set (a union of balls) for every point in A, since these balls are spheres centered at $(x_0,y_0, z_0)$ that's kind of my problem, am I clear about it ?